# Wrapping array of elements in spyne

Tags: python, xml, soap, spyne

I'm trying to construct a SOAP service with Spyne that has method `addUsers`, which takes a single argument (users - exactly one instance) provided in such structure:

```
<users>
  <user>
    <name>Jake</name>
    <age>123</age>
  </user>
  <user>
    ...
  </user>
  ...
</users>
```

I have the user specified like so:

```
class user(ComplexModel):
  name = String()
  age = Integer()
```

But how would I go about adding the `users`-wrapper? And what would the arguments to `@rpc()` decorator look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `Array(User)` ? It didn't work?

```
@rpc(Array(User))
def get_users(ctx, users):
    # (...)
```

Comment: It did, thanks. What actually got me confused was trying to test the API with suds while I wasn't even sure what kind of requests _it_ was generating. Took a step back, devised a test SOAP document by hand, executed with curl and viola, got confirmation that the spyne's generated version was correct.